# AVG blocks me from using Console.ReadKey() in C# Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, average, visual-studio-2017

I got on Visual Studio 2017 today and when I was following a tutorial I wrote Console.ReadKey(); and AVG said that my program was a Trojan Horse Virus. So now I could no longer run my program because AVG won't let me access the executable. I tried a little work around because I figure that this is all just a false-positive. But I want to know why all the sudden AVG just claims my program is a virus. This only happened today and the last time I got on Visual Studio 2017 it was fine for me to do Console.ReadKey(). So is there anyway I can fix this so that AVG will just let me do what I want?

Comment: Turn it off? There's not enough info in this question and most likely, it would be better asked at AVGs support desk. It is possible that your machine *is* actually compromised. What happens when you submit the file that you generated to https://www.virustotal.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVG is intercepting *Keyboard Hook* as virus. Go ahead and exclude your application folder or executable from AVG exclusions